# Undo fixups on a `git rebase -i`

Tags: git, rebase

I've seen a few posts here on undoing a `git rebase` but haven't come across anything that fits my particular case.

I've run the command `git rebase -i HEAD~10`

After running that, I did fixup to all commits but 3

The **first 2 commits is code written by someone else** here but only on one file, everything else for this branch was written by me across 5 files and **I am the author of the latest commit**. All commits between the first 2 and the last 1, I've applied fixup.

When I look at VS Code `git blame`, **I see all the code I wrote but it shows the other guy as the author of the code**.

Is there a way for me to undo the fixup so that I can redo the fixup so that I appear as the author for the code I wrote?

An example would be:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

terminal outputs

```
pick 12345 Commit 1
pick 12344 Commit 2
pick 12343 Commit 3
pick 12342 Commit 4
pick 12341 Commit 5
```

I apply the fixup so that it now looks like

```
pick 12345 Commit 1
pick 12344 Commit 2
fixup 12343 Commit 3
fixup 12342 Commit 4
pick 12341 Commit 5
```

I've now saved these changes.

When I look at my commit history it shows

```
Commit 1
Commit 2
Commit 5
```

My goal is to revert my changes so that when I run

> git rebase -i HEAD~5

It should look like this again:

```
pick 12345 Commit 1
pick 12344 Commit 2
pick 12343 Commit 3
pick 12342 Commit 4
pick 12341 Commit 5
```

Comment: You undo the fixup by undoing the rebase. You can do that like you undo any other rebase.

Comment: I didn't quite get what is your issue: authorship or content of certain changes?

Comment: Authorship is being heuristically calculated based on the amount of changes. But it's a good tone not to change authorship in any case. Regarding the content changes see first comment by @mkrieger1.

Comment: @0andriy the issue is with authorship.  I've tried running git reflog, the commits that i've applied fixup to are still combined.  I'm just trying to get to the point to where I can get a hold of all the original commits and apply the fixup properly to certain commits

Comment: Your comment brought even more confusion. Can you update the post to show how it is now and how you want it to be?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the original post

Comment: So, run `git reflog` followed by `git reset --hard $OLD_COMMIT_5`. The `$OLD_COMMIT_5` you may find in reference log until you run garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

for your case, you should follow these steps.

1. suppose your actual working branch is **Master** (or dev or any other name).
2. find your old commits which you have made a fixup by error, to do that you can run this command

   **git reflog**
3. suppose now you have found your commits by SHA-1, lets say **COMMIT_2**, **COMMIT_3** and **COMMIT_4**
4. checkout the commit before the fixup commits, in your case, it is **COMMIT_1**

   **git checkout COMMIT_1**
5. make a cheery-pick for old commits

   **git cherry-pick COMMIT_2**

   **git cherry-pick COMMIT_3**

   **git cherry-pick COMMIT_4**
6. now after making cherry-pick for your **COMMIT_4**, you should see an other SHA-1 (commit number) for this commit, lets say **COMMIT_4'**
7. go to your working branch

   **git checkout Master**
8. rebase your master on the last cherry-picked commit **COMMIT_4'**

   **git rebase COMMIT_4'**